# M Button is not Downloading Instead Redirect me to the file in the Browser

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a button that if clicked would download my pdf file, instead of that I get my button redirecting me to the file in the browser.

```
<a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tXsspgV_FiQoTUCI9qqd66vhw9Pr7PDp/view?usp=sharing"
download="javatest.pdf">
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary mx-3 mb-4" type="button">                    
  Download CV
  </button>
</a>
```

Comment: Please do not wrap a button with a link. If you want the link to look like a button, then [style the link](https://www.google.com/search?q=style+link+to+look+like+button+site:stackoverflow.com)